# mysql query but two differant group by

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

If my Data is

```
Name - playerID - matchID - Innings - Runs
James   1   1   1   5
James   1   1   2   8
Darren  2   1   1   3
Darren  2   1   2   9
James   1   2   1   10
James   1   2   2   12
Darren  2   2   1   13
Darren  2   2   2   19
```

and my sql data is

```
$query = "SELECT playerID, name,
        SUM(runs) AS runs_scored,
        MAX(runs) AS highest_score
    FROM matchPlayer GROUP BY playerID";
```

Then the output would read

```
James has scored 35 runs with a highest score of 18
Darren has scored 44 runs with a highest score of 19
```

Now I wish to get the highest total scored in one match (that is combining innings 1 & 2)?
I have no idea how to start on this query :(

EDIT
The exact info I require is the HIGHEST match total, so James has 13 combined runs from matchID 1 and 22 combined runs from matchID 2 - so the answer I am after is 22.

Comment: Highest per player per match or just per match?

Comment: Actually can you give your desired results for this example data? Seems we all interpreted your request differently...

Comment: @Martin - We sure did! :) 3 different answers that address differing interpretations of the problem.

Comment: @Martin I have edited the question.  Irony of all this is that I have learnt a lot of new things :)

Comment: @James in that case, Xint0 has it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it in two stages:

```
SELECT ms.playerID, mp.name, SUM(ms.runs_by_match) AS runs_scored,
    MAX(ms.runs_by_match) as highest_score
FROM
    matchPlayer as mp
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT playerID, matchID, SUM(runs) AS runs_by_match
        FROM matchPlayer
        GROUP BY playerID, matchID
    ) AS ms ON mp.playerID = ms.playerID
GROUP BY
    ms.playerID, mp.name
```